# Elasticsearch match combos of two fields

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

How can I get this simple SQL query running on Elasticsearch?

```
SELECT * FROM [mytype] where (id=123 and cid = classroomIdA) or 
(id=234 and cid = classroomIdB) or (id=345 and cid = classroomIdC)
```

I'm really having troubles with its syntax, multi-match queries doesn't work in my case. What type of query should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do it is to combine `bool/should` (for the outer OR conditions) and `bool/filter` (for the inner AND conditions) together.

```
POST mytype/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id": 123
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "cid": "classroomIdA"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id": 234
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "cid": "classroomIdB"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id": 345
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "cid": "classroomIdC"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The equivalent ES 1.7 query would be (just replace `bool/filter` by `bool/must`):

```
POST mytype/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id": 123
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "cid": "classroomIdA"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id": 234
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "cid": "classroomIdB"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id": 345
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "cid": "classroomIdC"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Val - thank you very much. Unfortunately we are using ES version 1.7. The above query works for only version > 2.x. Please let me know if you have a version for 1.x

Comment: lately this query is having performance issues when index size has grown to millions. And the bool **should** query array is having a size of 500. Is there a way you can provide me a optimized query?

Comment: Can you create a new question referencing this one and possibly sharing your big query? 500 should clauses sound like a few too many indeed.

Comment: Here is the new post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979163/elasticsearch-match-combos-of-two-fields-and-query-index-with-size-over-million

any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Val - can you please help?